# Updating another view in QT

Tags: qt

I have a database driven qt application which shows a list of customers and when you click on a customer it opens another window which allows you to edit the customers details and save it to the database.

This works fine but im wondering how I can trigger a refresh of the tableView in the other window.

In Objective-C there is something called delegates and i have a feeling this is similar but could someone clarify the proper way of doing this?

Thanks.

Patient List:

```
#include "patientlist.h"
#include "ui_patientlist.h"
#include "database.h"
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>

PatientList::PatientList(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::PatientList)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSqlQuery qry;

    if(qry.exec("SELECT patient_id,firstname,lastname FROM patients")){
        qDebug() << "Success";

        while(qry.next()){

            QTreeWidgetItem *itm = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
            QString label = QString(qry.value(0).toString());
            itm->setText(0,label);
            label = QString(qry.value(1).toString());
            itm->setText(1,label);
            label = QString(qry.value(2).toString());
            itm->setText(2,label);
            ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(itm);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error";
    }

    connect(
        ui->treeWidget, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)),
        this, SLOT(OnMouseDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int))
    );


}

PatientList::~PatientList()
{
    delete ui;
}

void PatientList::OnMouseDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int id)
{
    int patient_id = item->text(0).toInt();

    editPatient = new EditPatient();
    editPatient->loadPatient(patient_id);
    editPatient->show();
}
```

Edit Patient:

```
#include "editpatient.h"
#include "ui_editpatient.h"

EditPatient::EditPatient(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::EditPatient)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

EditPatient::~EditPatient()
{
    delete ui;
}

void EditPatient::loadPatient(int patient_id)
{

    clearForm();

    patient = new Patient();

    patient->Load(patient_id);

    if(patient->getPatientId() > 0){
        qDebug() << "Patient ID: " << patient->getPatientId();
        ui->patientidInput->setText(QString::number(patient->getPatientId()));
        ui->firstnameInput->setText(patient->getFirstname());
        ui->lastnameInput->setText(patient->getLastName());
    }

}


void EditPatient::clearForm()
{
    ui->patientidInput->setText("");
    ui->firstnameInput->setText("");
    ui->lastnameInput->setText("");
}

void EditPatient::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    patient->setFirstname(ui->firstnameInput->text());
    patient->setLastname(ui->lastnameInput->text());

    if(patient){
        patient->Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) are probably what you're looking for.

Add a signal to the EditPatient class header (which should be QObject-derived) like so:

```
signals:
void patientChanged(int patientId);
```

To the PatientList widget header, add:

```
public slots:
void handlePatientChanged(int patientId);
```

Implement *handlePatientChanged()*, and connect them with:

```
connect(_editPatientPointer, SIGNAL(patientChanged(int)), 
     ui->patientListPointer, SLOT(handlePatientChanged(int)));
```

Trigger the signal in EditPatient whenever needed, with:

```
emit patientChanged(patientId);
```

It would probably be better to use some architecture where the editPatient classes and similar forward their signals to a more implementation-decoupled interface class (say *DataModelInterface* or similar) and have the UI objects connect their slots to that.